# Show that there are 1120 elements of $S_8$ having disjoint cyclic decomposition of the type (a b c)(d e f)(g h)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that there are 1120 elements of $S_8$ having disjoint cyclic decomposition of the type (a b c)(d e f)(g h). Find also the number of elements in the orbit of (a b c)(d e f)(g h).

My reasoning to solve this problem is that first we can choose 3 elements out of 8 then 3 out of 5 and 2 out of the remaining 2. Then since three elements can constitute 2 different 3-cycles, the total number of elements should be $8C3*5C3*2*2$. But this is 2240 not 1120. Why should I divide this number by 2? And also, isn't the number of orbits of (a b c)(d e f)(g h), being the conjugacy class of it, equal to the number of disjoint cyclic decomposition of the type (a b c)(d e f)(g h)?

Comment: Since $(abc)(def)(gh)=(def)(abc)(gh)$, you have counted each element twice. It is not clear what is meant by the orbit of $(abc)(def)(gh)$. You need to specify an action to get orbits! If it is the conjugation action, then the answer is just $1120$.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is $${8\choose 3}{5\choose 3}{2\choose 2}.(3-1)!(3-1)!(2-1)!{1\over2}=1120$$

My answer copmletly depend on combinatorics reasoninig and at the and we divide by $2$ since $$(a,b,c)(d,e,f)(g,h)=(d,e,f)(a,b,c)(g,h)$$

**Example:** if want to calculate the elements of the form $(a,b)(c,d)(e,f)$ then at the and we should divide by $3!$. I hope the reason is clear now.